# How to store data from for loop inside of for loop? (rolling correlation in r)

Tags: r, loops, lapply, datastore

```
require(quantmod)
require(TTR)

iris2 <- iris[1:4]
b=NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(iris2)){
for (j in 1:ncol(iris2)){
a<- runCor(iris2[,i],iris2[,j],n=21)
b<-cbind(b,a)}}
```

I want to calculate a rolling correlation of different columns within a dataframe and store the data separately by a column. Although the code above stores the data into variable b, it is not as useful as it is just dumping all the results. What I would like is to be able to create different dataframe for each i.

In this case, as I have 4 columns, what I would ultimately want are 4 dataframes, each containing 4 columns showing rolling correlations, i.e. df1 = corr of col 1 vs col 1,2,3,4, df2 = corr of col 2 vs col 1,2,3,4...etc)

I thought of using lapply or rollapply, but ran into the same problem.

```
d=NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(iris2))
 for (j in 1:ncol(iris2))
{c<-rollapply(iris2, 21 ,function(x) cor(x[,i],x[,j]), by.column=FALSE)
d<-cbind(d,c)}
```

Would really appreciate any inputs.

Comment: try a `foreach` loop or `mapply` over the index vector.  It'll give you a list of lists of the list of DF.  Nested by `i` then `j` and then `c&d`

Comment: It is never a good idea to use cbind in a for loop. It's much better practice to use a list with predefined length to avoid copying excessively in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the expanded loop, how about a list of dataframes?

```
e <- list(length = length(ncol(iris2)))

for (i in 1:ncol(iris2)) {
  d <- matrix(0, nrow = length(iris2[,1]), ncol = length(iris2[1,]))
    for (j in 1:ncol(iris2)) {
        d[,j]<- runCor(iris2[,i],iris2[,j],n=21)
    }
e[[i]] <- d
}
```

It's also a good idea to allocate the amount of space you want with placeholders and put items into that space rather than use `rbind` or `cbind`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't think about this way and it works great. But a problem is that the actual data I'm running has more than 100 columns and it seems like it takes more than 20 mins to run the code... I simply want to see rolling correlation of data against all others, as I briefly mentioned in my question. Will there be any way to make it more efficient? Thanks again.

Comment: @sh2657  Your comment seems to have been cut off.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit enter and was editing it. Should be good now.

Comment: @sh2657  If you want to calculate the correlation for 100 columns,  100 times it's probably going to take a while. Using `foreach` and `mapply` as above will help, but it will still take a bit.

Comment: Should check those out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is **not** a good practice to create dataframes on the fly in R (you should prefer putting them in a list as in other answer), the way to do so is to use the `assign` and `get` functions.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(iris2)) { 
   for (j in 1:ncol(iris2)){
      c <-  runCor(iris2[,i],iris2[,j],n=21)

      # Assign 'c' to the name df1, df2...
      assign(paste0("df", i), c)
      }
}

# to have access to the dataframe:
get("df1")

# or inside a loop
get(paste0("df", i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated your computation was slow, I wanted to provide you with a parallel solution. If you have a modern computer, it probably has 2 cores, if not 4 (or more!). You can easily check this via:

```
require(parallel) # for parallelization
detectCores()
```

Now the code:

```
require(quantmod)
require(TTR)

iris2 <- iris[,1:4]
```

Parallelization requires the functions and variables be placed into a special environment that is created and destroyed with each process. That means a wrapper function must be created to define the variables and functions.

```
wrapper <- function(data, n) {
  # variables placed into environment
  force(data)
  force(n)

  # functions placed into environment
  # same inner loop written in earlier answer
  runcor <- function(data, n, i) {
    d <- matrix(0, nrow = length(data[,1]), ncol = length(data[1,]))
    for (j in 1:ncol(data)) {
      d[,i] <- TTR::runCor(data[,i], data[,j], n = n)
    }
    return(d)
  }

  # call function to loop over iterator i
  worker <- function(i) {
    runcor(data, n, i)
  }

  return(worker)
}
```

Now create a cluster on your local computer. This allows the multiple cores to run separately.

```
parallelcluster <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
models <- parallel::parLapply(parallelcluster, 1:ncol(iris2),
                              wrapper(data = iris2, n = 21))
stopCluster(parallelcluster)
```

Stop and close the cluster when finished.

Comment: You're the best. Thank you.